# Display IMAGE OR DATA through external TXT File

Tags: php, image, file, code-snippets

I have file1.txt and A PHP Code which increment it.
I have a snippet to display the image.
I paste a snippet in my website that displays Images by reading the data number from file1.txt.

I use the snippet multiple times in one page but I get the same result. What happens is that when the website page is loaded it reads the file1.txt having ,lets say number 10, image number.

What I want is that Snippet 1 Displays 10 Increment file1.txt 
then Snippet 2 Displays 11 and so on.

**how should i make the snippet in such a way that it waits for the increment and then reads it and then it displays image.**

**Example:** 
Snippet 1 >10th Image 
Snippet 2 >11th Image 
Snippet 3 >12th Image 
While all are executed in one page?

> One Way i Think might be that 
>  the snippet GET the wait.txt and
>   checks if its 1 or 0 
>  If It is 1 it waits for certain seconds then
>   execute the external php and if it is 0 it proceeds to executes the
>   external PHP.
>  Then External PHP on Execution Sets wait.txt to
>   1 while its being used and then once it has finished it sets the
>   wait.txt to 0
>
> But I doubt it will flawlessly work. I need you guys to help me out.

Okay the below code is what I have
The PHP Contains this:

```
$open = fopen("xml/file1.txt", "r+");
$num = fgets($open);
$close = fclose($open);
$num++;
$open = fopen("xml/file1.txt", "w+");
fwrite($open, $num); 
$close = fclose($open);
```

The Snippet

```
<?php
$myFile = "../xml/file1.txt";
$line= file($myFile);//file in to an array
$image = $line[0]; //So that it Reads the first line if 2nd line has /n
echo "<img src=''.$image.'.img'></img>";
/*Executing PHP through php as it as additional code in php 
  which does some other verifications.*/
echo '<script src="//localhost/image.php"></script>'; 
?>
```

The file1.txt Contains:

```
1 
//Ignore the comment here it just contain 1 number 
//which increment each time the snippet  executes the php
```

So I paste The snippet in one page Multiple times. But All snippet displays the same image instead of in ascending order. I want to find how can I do it? No MySql Database. And I don't want to list and read each line.

> I want my snippet to read the data from file1.txt after it has been
>   updated

I want my snippet to know that the php is busy and needs to wait while other snippet is using it. As my project will include heavy traffic I want it Optimized.

*Lastly I am a new to this so it's hard to figure out.*  
**THE CODE BELOW WORKS BUT HOW CAN I OPTIMISE IT for heavy traffic?**

```
    <?php
session_start();

waitque();
function waitque() {
$input = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$e = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$input = trim($input, '/');

    // If not have http:// or https:// then prepend it
    if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
        $input = 'http://' . $input;
    }

    $urlParts = parse_url($input);

    // Remove www.
    $dom = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);
if(isset($_SESSION['worker'])){

  $open = fopen("queue/imageindex.txt", "r+");
  $value = fgets($open);
  $close = fclose($open);
  $value++;
  $open = fopen("queue/imageindex.txt", "w+");
  fwrite($open, $value); // variable is not restated, bug fixed.
  $close = fclose($open);
    $myFile = "queue/imageindex.txt";
    $line= file($myFile);//file in to an array
    $relid = $line[0];
  echo $relid." Code PUBLISHED</div>";

    unset($_SESSION['worker']);
        } else {
            echo "<div>waiting...</div>";
            $_SESSION['worker']= $dom.$a.$ip;
      waitque();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think posting your code might help us make sense of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Okay Added The code Let me know.

Comment: adding a session based queue system would help? I mean just queueing the code to execute.

Comment: I have read this question 8 times and I still really don't know what you're trying to do. You are trying to display images on a webpage, correct? Why are you echoing a `<script>` tag? Why are you posting the "snippet" repeatedly instead of using a loop? Why are you using a text file to increment a number?  Help me understand!

Comment: I will use this snippet on external websites as well as my own. I am echoing <script> tag to execute the remote php file. Sorry if this seem confusing. I am using text file to reduce the load on MySql DB as my snippet will be used and executed thousands of times by visits on website. Sorry to be confusing.